# SlickGrid deleting a column does not delete its data

Tags: slickgrid

1. I am adding a new column to SlickGrid using of course grid.setColumns(newColumnDef);
2. I allow the user to then enter values into this new column
3. If they so choose they can remove this column and add another column which they can select from a dropdown list.

This all works fine, the column gets removed and the grid appears without the removed column. However when I call dataView.getItems() to grab the data from the grid the columns I'vd previously removed are still there. Looks like setColumns with a new column definition and dataView.refresh does not delete the columns data, just the column is removed. I need to remove the columns data when the column is removed... Any suggestions would be most helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the presentation of the data does not change the data itself.

Comment: It's your data and it's available to you in a JavaScript array.  Edit it however you want it.

Answer (score 0):

Use deleteItem method of dataview as follows,

```
    dataView.deleteItem(id);\\where id is your unique id
    dataView.refresh();`
```